# why "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" showing wrong time in SQL?

Tags: sql

I am using "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" for automatic date setup inside the column for each row in SQL. It shows date and time but time is wrong. please help.

Comment: it shows time on the server  where your database  is. check the server time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CURRENT_TIMESTAMP will show you the server timestamp not client side timestamp from where you are querying. 
Please check in which timezone your database server is located.